# Saved list as template doesn't appear in app catalog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, list-template

In the context of the same site collection and site, I saved a custom list (100) as template, it appears in list templates catalog, however, in the "Add an app" I cannot see the list template.

Why I cannot see the list template in the "add an app" catalog and how can I make it appear ? The idea is to reuse a list template whenever needed in the same site / site collection.

Comment: What is the type of your list template?

Comment: Generic list, 100

Comment: Which version of SharePoint & type of list you are using? Check the limitations at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/victorbutuza/list-saved-as-template-does-not-appear-under-add-an-app-or-what-lists-can-you-save-as-template-and-use-for-creating-other-lists-based-on-them

Comment: @GaneshSanap: Sharepoint 2013 enterprise version and Generic Custom List 100. If I understood correctly, the list template cannot be used in the same site ? I want to reuse it in the same site it has been created

Comment: Try to save another custom list as template, compare the result.

Comment: Tried, same result.